# Copying files and subfolders without -r

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm new to Linux,
I am trying to write a Bash script which will copy a directory's content to a backup folder which will be created, without using the -r switch.
I assumed that the max depth of the directory is 2 .
I placed in some echo's at the script and I have noticed that the for loop takes the first and only argument to be the path of the current folder - it absolutely ignores all files in the directory.
I tried changing the code a few times with no success.
Is there a syntax error? Is the logic not right? I would love to get an answer. Thanks alot!

```
pwd > route
r=$(<route)
cd ..
if [ ! -d backup ]; then
    mkdir backup
fi
cd backup
pwd > buroute
BUrout=$(<buroute)
cd "$r"
for i in $r; do
    if [ -f $i ]; then
        cp $i "$BUrout"
    fi
    if [ -d $i ]; then
        if [ $i == $r ]; then
            continue
        fi
        cd "$i"
        pwd > current
        cur=$(<current)'/'
        for file in "$cur"; do
            if [ -f "$file" ]; then
                cp $file "$BUrout"
            fi
        done
        cd ..
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite see why you can't just use `cp -r` or `rsync -a` for this, unless you explicitly want to flatten the directory structure, but never mind.

You're doing a lot to get the path to subdirectories:  `cd` into the directory, `pwd` to a file and then read that file into a variable.  Instead you could just use e.g. `BUrout="$PWD/backup"` (`$PWD` holds the pathname of the current working directory).

You will never process any files because your loop is over the name of a directory.  What you want is probably `for i in "$r"/*; do`, and similarly in the second loop.

*Always* double quote your variable expansions!  E.g. `if [ "$i" = "$r" ]` (note also single `=`, not double).  See both "[Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)" and "[Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)"

Your script should not need a single `cd`. Scripts that steps into and out of directories are *really* hard to debug.

Apart from that, no syntax errors, and the logic seems to be correct.

May I suggest something like this, which is still using the same looping logic and mostly the same tests as your code is using, but without the calls to `cd` and without having to fiddle too much with directory names:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

source="$1"
dest="$2"

mkdir -p "$dest"  # creates destination directory if not already exists

for name in "$source"/*; do
    if [ -f "$name" ]; then
        cp "$name" "$dest"
    elif [ -d "$name" ]; then
        for name2 in "$name"/*; do
            if [ -f "$name2" ]; then
                cp "$name2" "$dest"
            fi
        done
    fi
done
```

Or, using shortcut-syntax which seems to appeal to some people:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

source="$1"
dest="$2"

mkdir -p "$dest"  # creates destination directory if not already exists

for name in "$source"/*; do
    [   -f "$name" ] && { cp "$name" "$dest"; continue; }
    [ ! -d "$name" ] && continue
    for name2 in "$name"/*; do
        [ -f "$name2" ] && cp "$name2" "$dest"
    done
done
```

This script takes two arguments, the source directory and the target/destination directory:

```bash
$ ./script mydir some_new_backup_dir
```

No attempt is made to check whether any of the `cp` commands would overwrite an existing file in the target directory.

Note also that both of these scripts are `/bin/sh` script. They uses no things that are specific to the `bash` shell.

---

Assuming that the target directory exists, this is more or less equivalent to

```bash
find source_dir -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec cp {} target_dir ';'
```